# UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How would I access `{{c.key().id()}}` in my python file? It correctly prints out the correct id in my html. When I try to get the id from the request I get an error `UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'key'` but if I set the `id` to something such as 
`id=5222955109842944` it works.

When I used `id= Comment.key().id()` I get

```
id = Comment.key.id
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'or id= Comment.key.id
```

When I tried `id = Comment.key()` I got

```
id = Comment.key()
TypeError: unbound method key() must be called with Comment instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I have this in my python file

```
        #id=5222955109842944
        id = self.request.get('id')



        name = 'testname1'
        key = db.Key.from_path('Comment', id)

        comments = db.get(key)
```

When I try to get the id from the request I get an error `UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'key'`

This is in my html file:

```
  comment id{{c.key().id()}}


  <a href="/blog/editcomment?id={{c.key().id()}}">Edit Comment</a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.request.get('id')` is a string.  You need to turn it into an `int`:

`int(self.request.get('id'))`

Comment: @John If this answer helped you, you should consider accepting it (click the checkmark next to the answer) to indicate to other readers that this in fact solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I didn't know about the checkmark until today. I had been clicking on the up arrow which didn't work for me because I didn't have more than 15 reputation. Thanks again for your help.